# How to reduce the RAM usage by run_kernel in MACBook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

run_kernel is using upto 1gb of ram in macbook pro.Please help

Comment: Is this causing problems for your Mac? What behaviour are you seeing that suggests the RAM use needs to be reduced?

Comment: yes this is causing slow loading of various applications.

Answer (score 1):

`run_kernel` appears to be [associated with OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928305/sharing-opencl-kernel-data) and thus linked to work being performed by the graphics card in your MacBook Pro.

Consider [switching between graphics cards](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4152) and seeing if that helps.

Without more information, it is difficult to assist. A process using 1GB RAM is not in itself likely to be the cause of problems. Your MacBook Pro is likely 64-bit and is designed to work with much larger volumes of memory.

If you are running OS X 10.9 or later, try watching the Activity Monitor's Memory information. Do you see large, gigabyte or more, values for **Swap** or **Compressed** memory? What value do you see for **Wired Memory?**

Comment: Switching graphics is not an option in OS X 10.9.My laptop configuration is 13" mid level macbook configuration 4GB 2.5GHZ i5 processor. Other stats are 1.15GB for Wired memory in activity monitor.Swap used in 3.86GB.